# How to generate times of sunset along a line that crosses a continent?

Tags: sunset

Would like to avoid using single location iteration of a website that gives time of sunset each date for locations.

I want to be able to produce a chart or info-graphic for publishing on a website as a guide for participants stretching from nyc,through Lebanon KS,to San Francisco.

A great circle path with formula or algorithm to produce the table or graph???

interval of time would be June to November only

Comment: Great question and there are a couple of ways to go on this. There can be answers that cite books with astronomical algorithms that you can put in a spreadsheet for example, and even simple computer programs. Do you have any experience using some simple Python or have access to someone who can assist you running a Python script?

Comment: I won't be able to post a Python-based answer soon, but there's this: https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/almanac.html look for the `almanac.sunrise_sunset()` method

Comment: I shall research this idea. No python experience but a willing student.

Comment: Skyfield apparent is program that does this kind of calculation? How daunting a task is that for a complete newbie to install and tinker? Looks pretty overwhelming. Thx for the lead...

Comment: I can post a short script that you can run in the next day or so and I'm happy to do so! All you'd need to do is run it. It means either installing Python on a computer or finding someone who can run it for you.

Comment: Sweet! I owe you. Pass it forward my task now, me thinks. I have learned much about the overwhelming and "over my head". Sorry, pun to much to resist.

Comment: I think that means yes, so I will

Comment: YES! Greedy perhaps but across a continent of North America, specifically 48 contiguous states with Lebanon KS as the mid point of east/west grand circle nyc(or similar east coast point DC?) & San Francisco or similar west coast...  but happy for anything. Thx again.